# Given a Positive Definite Matrix, find conditions of elements inside the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification

I have a question that asks me to use the following symmetric positive definite matrix of order $n + 1$

$$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha & a^T \\
 a & A
\end{bmatrix}
$$

With this matrix, I have to show that the scalar $\alpha$ must be positive and the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ must be positive definite.

My attempt:

Given that the matrix $B$ is positive definite, we know that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 & \vec{x_2}
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha & a^T \\
    a & A
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 \\
    \vec{x_2}
\end{bmatrix} > 0
$$

and therefore

$$\alpha x_1^2 + 2ax_1\vec{x_2} + A\vec{x_2}^2 > 0$$
$$\alpha x_1^2 + 2ax_1\vec{x_2} + \vec{x_2}^TA\vec{x_2} > 0$$

We know that $\alpha$ must be positive because if $\alpha$ was negative then there would exist some vector $x$ such that $\alpha x_1^2 + 2ax_1\vec{x_2} + \vec{x_2}^TA\vec{x_2} \leq 0$. We also know that $A\vec{x_2}^2 > 0$ by the same reasoning. As a result, matrix $A$ must be positive definite since we know that

$$
 A\vec{x_2}^2 = \vec{x_2}^TA\vec{x_2} > 0
$$

which is the definition of a positive definite matrix.

Would this proof work for showing that $\alpha$ is positive and that $A$ is a positive definite matrix?

Comment: I think it's important to point out exactly choices of $x_1$ and $\vec{x_2}$ that make it work instead of just saying they exist. Otherwise it looks fine to me. See also [Cauchy's Interlacing Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/853228/55235).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll make sure to add that in and also look into Cauchy's Interlacing Theorem.